# Chatrooms Not showing in homeScreen flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to bring chat room data from firebase and show it in my dashboard screen,

for now i just wanna receive the users list as a simple text but it's just showing Circular Progress Indicator

```
    Future<Stream<QuerySnapshot>> getChatRooms() async {
      return firestore
          .collection("chatRooms")
          .orderBy("lastMessageSendTs", descending: true)
          .where("users", arrayContains: Email)
          .snapshots();
    }
  
    chatRooms() async {
      ChatRoomsStream = await getChatRooms();
      setState(() {});
    }
  
    Widget chatRoomsList() {
      return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: ChatRoomsStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return snapshot.hasData
              ? ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    DocumentSnapshot ds =
                        snapshot.data?.docs[index] as DocumentSnapshot<Object?>;
                    return Text(ds.id.replaceAll(Email, "").replaceAll("_", ""));
                  })
              : CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      );
    }

  ),

 isSearching ? searchUserslist() : chatRoomsList(),
      ],
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Widget chatRoomsList() {
      return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: firestore
          .collection("chatRooms")
          .orderBy("lastMessageSendTs", descending: true)
          .where("users", arrayContains: Email)
          .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return snapshot.hasData
              ? ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    DocumentSnapshot ds =
                        snapshot.data?.docs[index] as DocumentSnapshot<Object?>;
                    return Text(ds.id.replaceAll(Email, "").replaceAll("_", ""));
                  })
              : CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      );
    }
```